# is there any way to preview rendered image from command line while running script?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I have written a script to render animation, i set camera location as a command line argument for rendering so actually i want to provide to user rendered first frame of animation as an image to visualize to verify that the camera location is right and animation character is in range of camera view else user can change camera location accordingly, is there any way to do this, i tried to use matplotlib.pyplot to visualize rendered first frame image from command line while running blender from background, but i think 3rd party modules installation is very hectic. Is there any other way to do this?
I am using Windows10, blender 2.79b